# Lost water in sous vide container overnight

Tags: food-safety

I had 2 roasts in my sous vide at 132 degrees for 10 hours and went to bed at 10 and checked at 7 this morning and had no water as had sprung a leak
Planned on cooking for 36 hours so started again
Will the meat be safe after sitting with no water for that long

Comment: It won’t help now, but you can loose a lot of water to evaporation.  You want a container that’s significantly larger than the items to be cooked (so there’s lots of water), and cover the container as best you can.  Some people also use floating plastic balls (kinda look like ping pong balls, but not sure if they’re something different) to minimize the surface area of the water exposed to the air).  Lids or the balls also minimize temperature differentials as they reduce evaporative cooling

Comment: @Joe...while this is true, I believe he sprung a leak.

Answer (score 3):

Your meat was in the danger zone for too long, basically sitting at the perfect temperature for pathogen growth for many hours.  I would say that it is risky to continue.  "Two roasts" suggest you are feeding a lot of people.  Consider your guests.  I would go to plan b or start over with fresh product.

Comment: That is what I thought! Thanks for the answer. Dang it

Comment: That's too bad @TimWallen!